# Conflicting/duplicate column names in J()?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables (`dat` and `results`) that share column names. On a side note, `results` holds summary statistics computed earlier on **sub**groups of `dat`. In other words, `nrow(results) != nrow(dat)` (but I don't think this is relevant for the question)
Now I want to incorporate these results back into `dat` (i.e. the original data.table) by adding a new column (i.e. NewColZ) to `dat`

This doesn't work as I expect:

```
dat[,list(colA,colB,NewColZ=results1[colX==colX & colY==colY,colZ])
   ,by=list(colX, colY)]
```

Why? because "colX" and "colY" are columns names in both data.tables (i.e. dat and results). What I want to say is, `results1[take_from_self(colX)==take_from_parent(colX)]`

Therefore the following works (observe I have only RENAMED the columns)

```
dat[,list(colA,colB,NewCol=results1[cx==colX & cy==colY,colZ,])
   ,by=list(colX, colY)]
```

Though I have a feeling that this can simply and easily be done by a join. But `dat` has many more columns than `results`

Comment: where is the parent `colX` and `colY` coming from.  Also, have you read the FAQ?  This is addressed there

Comment: take_from_parent() simply refers to the dat data.table. Also, the FAQ talks has a question on the scoping rules of j , but here I looking for the scoping rules of i.

Comment: -1, Could we have the/a data? What is it that you expect the code to do (in a clear manner)? And what is it doing instead (again, in a clear and concise manner)? This is a very poorly formatted question ATM. I'd be happy to up-vote after significant changes to this question.

Comment: I think you've to read this post: [How to make a great reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: While `J()` might be useful for what the OP wants to do, I think it is again misused in the title of this post. Anyway, the OP might want to delete the question after learning more about data.table syntax. As-is, the q's very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a `join` on `colX` and `colY`. You can use `:=` to assign by reference. Joining is most straightforward when you have unique combinations (which I am assuming you do)

```
keys <- c('colX', 'colY')
setkeyv(dat, keys)
setkeyv(results, keys)

dat[results, newcolZ := colZ]
# perhap use `i.` if there is a colZ in dat
# dat[results, newcolZ := i.colZ]
```

I do concur with the comments that suggest reading the FAQ and introduction vignettes as well as going through the many examples in `?data.table`.

Your issue was a scoping issue, but your primary issue was not being fully aware of the data.table idioms.  The `join` approach is the idoimatically `data.table` approach.